# Get first td text to delete items in localstorage array

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm currently working on a project of mine in order to build a cart in the localstorage. Everything works except for deleting items on Local Storage based on given values.

I'm creating a dynamic table using the array in the localstorage. The table code is:

```
    <table id="response">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>prova</td><td>40</td><td><button class="myID" 
    onclick="deleteRow(this)">X</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>test</td><td>30</td><td><button class="myID" 
    onclick="deleteRow(this)">X</button></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

However when I try to delete the item clicking the button and using the first td on the same row as a value, the following code don't work properly:

```
   function deleteRow(r) {
   var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item')); 

   var value = jQuery(r).find("td:first").text;

   for (var k in arr) {
   var name = arr[k].name ;
   if (name === value) {

    arr.splice(k, 1);

    localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(arr));
     }
   else {
    alert('falso');
    }
   }   
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("response").deleteRow(i);
   }
```

The problem must be in the var value because if I assign to it a given value (e.g. "test") the function clear the corrispondent item in the localstorage array.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the jQuery selector you're using to get the text: `...find('td:first').text;`

It should be: `...find('td:first').text();`

[Here's a quick fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41wkvfhg/) using your same table markup, and a little click handler that receives an entire row, like your `deleteRow()` function, just to help troubleshoot. With the correct `text()` call, it writes the text value to the console as you'd expect.

```js
$(document).ready( function($) {
 $('#response tr').on('click', function(e) {
   console.log($(this).find("td:first").text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="response">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>prova</td><td>40</td><td><button class="myID">X</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>test</td><td>30</td><td><button class="myID">X</button></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Dear slothluvchunk thank you for your reply it works now! Thank you again, next time I'll check the syntax better! :)